# How to include base_url for Ajax calls in Laravel?

Tags: ajax, laravel

I am facing a problem after installing a `Laravel` project on localhost downloaded from my live web application

> The requested URL /releves/store-paiement/1 was not found on this server.
>   When I saw what the link calls, I found that it goes directly to the function using this link

```
http://localhost/releves/store-paiement/1
```

But the correct link is

```
http://localhost/projectname/releves/store-paiement/1
```

So is there a way to correct this by prepending the `projectname` without going through all the links in my application?

Comment: what you have in your .env file APP_URL?

Comment: http://localhost

Comment: So Laravel works fine and you only have problems with ajax calls? I think that if the base url of your project is `http://localhost/projectname`, that's what you should have in `.env` file `APP_URL`. But I wouldn't change it if you tell me that laravel works anyway.